# How to dismantle marvin window to repair latch?

Tags: repair, window-frame, latches

The latch on one of my marvin windows (~25 years old) "fell off" and dropped down inside the thin wood-covered plastic trim.  How do I get that piece (labelled "A" in the images) off to see if I can repair / replace the latch?

I've managed to pull up the bottom trim piece "B" and the white "fake-caulk" on the left side next to the piece I need to remove.

Since the bottom and top pieces pulled out, I'm assuming the side piece I need to remove also pulls out, but it's not coming easily and it's not clear which way it has to move, and what other pieces may have to be removed first, for it to come off.

[image: Broken Latch]
[image: Bottom left view from outside]
[image: Top left view from outside]

Comment: Is the piece metal so you can use a magnet on the outside to slide it up to grab it?

Comment: A is not removable, magnet on a string will get it

Comment: A strong enough magnet current will go through Part A and still pull it up. Rare earth magnets come to mind.

Comment: Have you contacted Marvin? Since they put them together, they can probably tell you how to take them apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The side piece "A" is in fact removable, although it was not easy.  It is embedded in a thin groove on the inside, as can be seen in the image below.  By first prying out the white weatherstrip/seal on the bottom for a few inches, one can then pry it out of the groove and slowly work your way up to the top.  The outside is held in place by snapping into a groove in the wood, so once the inside is free, the outside can be snapped out and the whole piece removed.
[image: Side strip removed]
The latch piece itself was still mostly intact, but had just disconnected from the upper-latch connecting rod and fallen to the bottom.  I was not able to retrieve it with either a magnet or a long skinny grabber.  Even if I had, I don't think I would have been able to reconnect it to the latch connecting rod with the side moulding/cover still in place.  Images below show the lower and upper latch mechanisms.  As can be seen, the operating lever is not captive; it engages in a grooved slot in the lower mechanism.
[image: lower latch mechanism]
[image: upper latch mechanism]

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your own question! Please be sure to click the check mark next to your answer so that others know that there is an answer to this question should they run into a similar situation.